# How to actually jump bridge in Pocket Edition?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

In Bedrock Edition, we can bridge by placing blocks in front of us that seems like scaffolding, and the most prominent from them is the MJ bridge, but I want to find ways on doing jump bridging.

Since I use a phone for playing Bedrock, it is actually quite difficult to do such bridging. Tapping fast really doesn't work, and the reach for mobile users is lower compared to PC/controller users if we were to consider the scaffolding methods.

So since this is how we will go about, how to properly do the jump bridge on Mobile? It's quite hard and I don't know how to master it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually impossible to jump bridge using Mobile, given the reasons I already specified in the question. It's better to just safe bridge because it can maintain the reach for mobile users.

With that being said, it is also impossible to MJ bridge. If you really want to do some jump bridging, you can try Java tellybridging, but it is not suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I’d tend to agree... however I have seen people sprint bridging (without jumping) on IPad. This technique involves spam clicking and sprinting across the void, although I am sure it is much more difficult on an IPhone. While this method isn’t as reliable as console jump-bridging, it’ll do in a pinch. Hopefully this helps!

Comment: I know how safe bridging works, but we do it slowly to avoid falling off. This answers it, but I won't accept it.

Answer (score -1):

U can jump bridge on mobile, but not jump bridging as in placing the block first on the air, rather than placing the block on an existing block or on existing blocks.